# Kendo Controls - SCRIPT28: Out of stack space

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I'm testing very standard kendo controls, every time I click on the pie chart or any of the other charts, for example, I'm getting the "out of stack space" in the browser. Anyone else getting this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#piechart").kendoChart({
        dataSource: ds_array
        seriesDefaults: {
            type: "pie",
            labels: {
                visible: true
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: "Monthly Revenue per Location"
        },
        legend: {
            position: "bottom"
        },
        series: [{
            field: "revenue",
            categoryField: "location"
        }],
        tooltip: {
            visible: true,
            format: "N0"
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Would be easy posting some sample code in JSBin or JSFiddle that  reproduces the problem? You have included `kendoChart` but we don't have the `DataSource` and just to make sure that is not something related with your data.

Comment: I've tried this in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/WQ7WQ/2/) and it works (IE9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that the version of the jquery js file was outdated. I downloaded the newest one (1.8.3) and it worked fine.